# WCF esk with .NET

Tags: .net, wcf, esb

We have a need to develop a WCF app that will form a key part of an ESB.

Unfortunately, some of the machines that need to access theses services have .NET 2.0 and there is a good chance that they won't want to update them.

Is there a technology that can be used to speak to a WCF endpoint without using > .NET 2.0?

Sockets etc?

Thank you muchly!

Answer (score 3):

.NET 2.0 was easily able to connect to and utilize SOAP based web services.

Just ensure that you have a SOAP endpoint on your WCF services and you shouldn't have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For the WCF services, use `BasicHttpBinding` (config: basicHttpBinding). On the 2.0 boxes, wsdl.exe should be able to import everything and generate decent proxies.

Comment: Guys,I have done some experimenting with this and as suggested it looks good! One thing I don't understand is when I create the noddy WCF 3.5 web service with its default 'string GetData(int value)' call the 2.0 proxy has an string GetData(int value, bool valueSpecified) signature? if I change from int to string or complex type the autogenerated 'valuespecified' is no longer present. If i repeat with 3.5 -> 3.5 there is no auto generated parameter what I want is to understand what this is called so I can google and better understand? Thank you!